# Entity Framework : when I filter by exact datetime, I get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework and I want to filter some data from the database. When I try to do it like this:

**Edit**: I want live search by date field.
If I wrote 10 the output must:

**All rows which birthday contains 10** . For example:

**10.12.2020**,    **10.10.2020**, **12.10.2020**, **12.12.2010**

and I tried

```
1) var sm = _db.SomeModel.Include(d => d.OtherModel).AsQueryable();
   sm.Where(x => x.birthday.toString("dd.MM.yyyy").contains(birthday));

2) var sm = _db.SomeModel.Include(d => d.OtherModel).AsQueryable();
   sm.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.birthday.toString("dd.MM.yyyy"), $"%{birthday}%"));
```

My Model:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ContactInfoId {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Birthday {get; set;}
    public ContactInfo Contact {get; set;}
}

public partial class ContactInfo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int TypeId {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public EmailType Type {get; set;}
}

public partial class EmailType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string value {get; set;}
}
```

and my controler

```
    var cust = _db.Customer.Include(e => e.ContactInfo).ThenInclude(e => e.EmailType).OrderBy(e => e.Lastname).AsQueryable();
cust = cust.Where(d => !d.Birthday.HasValue || (Convert.ToDateTime(d.Birthday).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains(birthday.toString)));
```

I get a SQL error.

How can I filter by exact datetime format?
And error is

```
.Where(c => !(c.Outer.Outer.Outer.Birthday.HasValue) || Convert.ToDateTime((objet)c.Outer.Outer.Outer.Birthday).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains() couldnt be translated
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Those are localized strings, not exact `DateTime`s. They're guaranteed to cause conversion errors. As for the query - is this a school or interview assignment? Nobody performs such queries in production. Nobody is going to retrieve records on both the Battle of Hastings in 1066 *and* the end of the Battle of Britain in October 1940

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your data model, you should use something like:

```
DateTime birthdayForSearch = DateTime.ParseExact(birthday, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
_db.SomeModel.Where(x => x.birthday.Date == birthdayForSearch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code:

```
    var sm = _db.SomeModel.ToList()
.Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.birthday).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains(birthday));
```

Comment: No it doesnt work.  it gives `couldn't translated` error

Comment: @NAO, can you show me your current code and model ? When i use these code, it works.

Comment: @NAO, use `_db.SomeModel.ToList()` instead of `AsQueryable()`.